# Django: How to programatically change superuser and/or staff status of a user

Tags: python, django, root

I'm creating an admin interface for a customer (separate from the supplied Django admin interface), and I need a way to change a user's superuser/staff status.

I can fetch the User object for a specified user, but I don't know how to change the superuser/staff status for that User.

Not surprisingly, doing

```
user.is_superuser = False
```

didn't work.

Comment: Are you saving after setting it to False? I just tried your code and it is working for me. If you are saving the model please post all of the involved code.

Comment: Ugh, that's all it was.  I forgot to save. In case anyone else is looking for the answer, don't forget to do user.save() after the changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See Scott Woodall's comment above.  I forgot to do:

```
user.save()
```

which commits the changes.